# Cant compile with std::atomic<int> as class member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static, g++, atomic

I have written a class in which I would like to have an atomic integer which should be initially set to -1.

```
#ifndef MIGRATINGTHREADS_VERTEX_H
#define MIGRATINGTHREADS_VERTEX_H

#include <set>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class vertex{
public:
    vertex(){};
    int id;
    bool visited = false;
    std::set <int> adjacencyList;

private:
    static std::atomic<int> matched{-1};
};

#endif
```

Since I have set matched to `static` I apparently needed to initialize it out of line as shown. However when I attempt to compile using `g++ -std=c++14 -latomic` I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccRJwQzu.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `vertex::matched'
/tmp/ccp52lOu.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Additionally, if I attempt to do the initialization in this manner

```
class vertex{
public:
    vertex(){};
    int id;
    bool visited = false;
    std::set <int> adjacencyList;

private:
    static std::atomic<int> matched;
};
```

I get the following errors pertaining to atomic constructors

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘vertex::vertex(vertex&&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from getVGraph.h:12:0,
                 from vertexcentric.cpp:15:
vertex.h:13:7: note: ‘vertex::vertex(vertex&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class vertex{
       ^~~~~~
vertex.h:13:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/stdc++.h:100:0,
                 from vertexcentric.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/atomic:668:7: note: declared here
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
```

I only have one definition of matched here however the compiler believes there to be multiple definitions. Is this an issue with atomics as class members, or my initialization?

Comment: Try putting `std::atomic<int> vertex::matched{-1};` in a source file.

Comment: First of all you need to learn about [header include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). Then after that you need to learn about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which is the key behind the first of your problems.

Comment: Header guards are present as the updated code reflects. They were just not added included in the initial code snippet.

Comment: Then on to the concept of *translation units*. In short, a translation unit is a *single* source file with all included header files (what usually creates a single object file). Multiple translation units (object files) can be linked together to form a single executable. A can only be defined in a *single* translation unit (the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)). With your (old and no longer shown) header file, you define `vertex::matched` in *multiple* translation units, once each where the file is included.

Comment: François Andrieux why does that work while having it in the header gives the multiple definition error?

Comment: *"Since I have set `matched` to static..."* - that isn't true in the first source listing. At least not in the code you posted here.

Comment: @Tokth Because your header is included by several source files (translation units) which will each claim to contain a definition for your `static` member. If you put it in a source file, only that translation unit will contain a definition.